# Flash AS2 - Dynamic text to open new window and make javascript call

Tags: javascript, flash

I have XML displaying in dynamic text boxes. Some of the text are a href links, I also want to track which links are clicked by sending a javascript call to Google Analytics. Is there a way to do it and also open the link in a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called "asfunction". See more here http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15639.html or here http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary073.html.

However if the text from XML is dynamic you would have to replace the stings on the fly. Use the original url as a parameter and receive it as paramaeter in the function.